# How to make width grow slowly when I add element?

Tags: css, css-animations, angular-material

I have next elements:

```
 <button ng-click="showChild2 = !showChild2"

<div class="parent" flex>
   <div class="child1">CHILD_1</div>
   <div ng-if='showChild2' class="fade child2">CHILD_2</div>   
</div>
```

CSS: fade is ng-animate class.

```
.child1 {width: 100px;}
.child2 {width: 100px;}
```

When I click button:
parent element width sharply becomes 200px,  and than slowly slides out child2 element.

I want parent element width grows with the same speed as slide out. How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `@keyframes` to your class `.fade`, and set the overflow on hidden (otherwise the text will overflow the original div).

```css
    .child1 {width: 100px;}
    .child2 {width: 100px; background-color: #F00; overflow:hidden}
    .fade {animation: fadeIn 1s}
    
    @keyframes fadeIn {
        from {width: 0px;}
        to {width: 100px;}
    }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child1">CHILD_1</div>
   <div ng-if='showChild2' class="fade child2">CHILD_2</div>   
</div>
```